# Ограничение на количество вводимых строк в NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, mac, objective-c

Есть поле для ввода текста NSTextView. Что нужно:

1. ограничить количество вводимых символов до 150 максимально;
2. максимальное количество строк ограничить до 4.

Первое сделать достаточно просто. А вот по второму пункту у меня проблема. Я могу посчитать количество строк текста в поле

```
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [NSTextView layoutManager];
NSUInteger numberOfLines, index, numberOfGlyphs = [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
NSRange lineRange;

for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++){
    [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index effectiveRange:&lineRange];
    index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
}
```

А вот как его обрезать до нужного количества строк?

Answer (score 1):

Можно считывать количество линий при вводе каждого символа (проверять для количество символов + 1) и, если превышен лимит строк, сделать поле неизменяемым.

Добавлено: [Getting Started with Pasteboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbGettingStarted.html).

Comment: Так и делаю, но проблема остается, когда надо вставлять большой кусок текста.

Comment: Хм, но ведь можно считывать, например, содержимое буфера обмена (ссылка в ответе) и уже считать количество новых строк, считая это содержимое.